# Lambda function unable to access internet

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I would like my lambda function to be able to access the internet. I have followed the following AWS tutorial: [AWS Knowledge Center Videos: How do I give internet access to my Lambda function in a VPC?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JcRKdEP94jM)

I have created a NAT.

[image: nat created]

Then I created a `public-lambda` network and created a route table that forwards default traffic to the NAT

[image: subnet routing table]

Then on my `lambda` function I have attached it to the `public-lambda` network

[image]

Inside my lambda function I make a request to a server out on the web. It just times out. I don't get logs on why it timed out but I'm assuming it wasn't able to reach the internet.

Why I'm not being able to access the internet from my lambda function?

Comment: Check the Outbound rules for the lambda SG. Additionally, are you using the default lambda timeout (3sec)? Try increasing it. Maybe it is timed out because the external dependency takes more than 3secs

Comment: @OmarRosadio I tried doing that but no luck. I tried hitting this public endpoint from my personal computer and it took me 200ms. It shouldn't take much longer from lambda

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you want to attach your Lambda function to the VPC? If not, simply detach it and it will have Internet access by default. However, if the function also needs to access resources in the VPC, then attach the Lambda function to a **private subnet** and put a NAT Gateway in a public subnet.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I have a RDS in that VPC and a beanstalk in another VPC. Since my Beanstalk can't be private (because its a single instance) I need access to the internet. I have fixed the issue. Will post an answer to it

Answer (score 1):

After watching [AWS: How to Place Your Lambda Functions in a VPC - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yMzb48BL7qQ) I was able to fix my issue.

The fix was that I needed to create a `private subnet` and create a routing table to route all default traffic to the NAT.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein exactly. Fixed it. Thank you for taking the time

Answer (score 0):

if your subnet has outbound access to internet(NAT/IGW) then definitely you lambda will get access to the internet.

first check with the subnet, try to spin one ec2 instance into that subnet and check the outbound connectivity using ping or curl.

second check the attached SG with lambda function.

just give a try, best of luck.

Comment: spinned a micro instance to test it out and it indeed has connection to the internet. The security group also has a default rule `0.0.0.0/0` to forward all traffic to the NAT gateway